# Rotate back to 0 degrees Logarithmically

Tags: math, rotation, exponential

When the user releases their finger I want my sprite to rotate back to 0 degrees. At the moment it is done like this:

```
if (touching == NO && rotationValue != 0)
{
    if (rotationValue < 180 && rotationValue < 0)
    {
        rotationValue += 1.5; 
    }
    else
    {
        rotationValue -= 1.5;
    }

    if (rotationValue < 1 && rotationValue > -1)
        rotationValue = 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me so when the sprite rotates back Logarithmically, so it starts rotating faster then slows down as it reaches 0.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  As I'm sure you're aware, you'll need to add different amounts to `rotationValue` on every iteration; which part of that is causing you an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to subtract a fraction of the difference left each tick. 0.125 here is an arbitrary parameter, you can change it to change the overall speed.

```
if (fabs(rotationValue) < 0.00000000000000000001){
    rotationValue = 0.0;
} else {
    rotationValue -= .125 * fabs(rotationValue);
}
```

Comment: this will give you exponential decay, which only approaches the goal asymptotically.  It's only due to limited floating point precision that you will eventually reach 0.  I'd combine the proportional term with a very small constant value to make sure you get there in a reasonable time.

Comment: I meant something like this: `rotationValue -= (.125 * fabs(rotationValue) + 0.02).`  See [the difference on Wolfram Alpha:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-x%29%2C+exp%28-x%29+-+0.02x%2C+x+%3D+0+to+5%2C+y+%3D+0+to+1)

Comment: Yes, you have to check for overshoot too.

Comment: It's better to just clamp it when it's close to 0 like I did. It's clearer and more concise.

Comment: I am not trying to start an argument, but - the clamp will either 1) still take a long time moving very slowly as it approaches 0, or 2) abruptly stop when it's still moving fast.